# Program to force a window to appear in the center of the primary monitor

Tags: windows, window-manager

I am looking for a program that runs on Windows 7 and can force a window of belonging to an application (running or at launch) to appear in the center of the primary monitor (assume a multi-monitor configuration). Free if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about free, but I use [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) and [UltraMON](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/).

Either or both of these will do exactly what you're looking for ;)

Comment: Thanks, I also use DisplayFusion and UltraMON but I don't see any option to force a window of belonging to a running application to appear in the center of the primary monitor :/

Answer (score 1):

Dang it, I apologize for having to create a new answer to answer you (your comment) but I'm new here and I do not have enough rep to comment back >.< (also created that on a 'guest' account before I finally created this "real" account. But now to actually answer you (this whole part can be edited out by a mod please?)[wont happen again, I promise, now that I have an account ;)]

Right click the DisplayFusion tray icon, go to the 'settings' then 'functions'. It doesn't appear to have a single command to accomplish what you desire, but you could always use the command to relocate the window (until you get it on the primary monitor), using "Move Window to Next (or Previous) Monitor". By default the keyboard shortcut for that is CTRL + WIN + X / W (respectively). Then use "Move Window to Center of Monitor". By default the keyboard shortcut for center window on monitor is CTRL + WIN + Q. So it would appear it is set up by default to be able to do this. You would not have to change anything in the settings unless you wanted to change the actual keyboard shortcuts.

UltraMON does appear to have a "Move window to primary monitor" feature under "hotkeys", but no feature to center a window. Also, UltraMON doesn't have any of the "hotkeys" set by default, so you would have to manually set up any hotkey (keyboard shortcut) features you desire from UltraMON.

Comment: Awesome, thanks I'll give a shot and let you know!